# Cannot ping a variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm still very much a noob in scripting in powershell but I cannot fathom why the following to work. And I believe it why I cannot get some variables to set.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $s
PC04PA71


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ping $s

Ping request could not find host PC04PA71
. Please check the name and try again.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ping PC04PA71

Pinging PC04PA71.xxx.xxx.xxx.com [xxx.xxx.190.160] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xxx.190.160: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=124
```

Comment: I am guessing you have an extra space at the end of your variable. What's the output of `$s.length`?

Comment: Try `ping $s.Trim()` or `ping $s[0].Trim()`.

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $s.length
8

Well hot damn. I cannot believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

try to trim your variable and dont forget you can use Test-Connection in PowerShell

```
Test-Connection $s.Trim()
```